# PHP 5.3 namespaces in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I am getting started with Symfony 2 & I am following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html) tutorial. Now, this tutorial is easy & I was able to follow it completely. This is the code in my Controller

```
<?php
namespace DemoCompany\HelloBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HelloController{
    public function indexAction($name){
        return new Response('<h1>hello ' . ucfirst($name) . '</h1>');
    }
}
```

Now, I have some questions

1. When I run the code without including `namespace DemoCompany\HelloBundle\Controller;`, it gives me an error. But it does work fine when this line is included; so I want to know: Why does it work with namespace statement & why doesn't it work without namespace. Please clarify.
2. Follow up question: I am returning a new `Response` object but it is neither being defined, nor is my class `HelloController` extending some baseclass (which may have this response object defined). So the question is: How is PHP able to find & then load this file?
3. In Symfony, do custom controllers/models/views need to extend some base class? For example, in Codeigniter, we have to do something like `class Blog extends CI_Controller`, so that all the methods defined in CI_Controller would be available in current scope using `$this`. Does Symfony have the same practice or does it do something different?
4. Since this controller is namespaced to `DemoCompany\HelloBundle\Controller`, how come normal PHP functions work without a backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only very briefly used Symfony2, here are my answers though:

1) That'll be because Symfony needs your Controller to exist in the `DemoCompany\HelloBundle\Controller` namespace for autoloading

2) At `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;`, you're telling PHP to look in there if the method can't be found locally

3) Don't know on that one...

4) Built-in PHP functions aren't in any specific namespace (namespaces are new to PHP), so work anywhere

Comment: Re 4: Actually built-in functions are in global namespace, so if a function `func()` is not found in current namespace, PHP falls back for a `func()` from global namespace. You can call such functions explicitly by prefixing them with \ like `\func()`

Comment: Re 4: for built-in objects however you need the backslash like: new \SplFileObject

Answer (score 5):

1: Namespaces act as 'folders' of sorts, with which you can encapsulate items to avoid naming collisions. You should go ahead and read all of PHP Documentation on the matter: [Namespaces overview](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php). Not including it means that you are using the global namespace, or `\`, while using it tells PHP that everything in the file belongs to the declared namespace, such that the fully qualified name for `HelloController` becomes `DemoCompany\HelloBundle\Controller\HelloController`

2: The `Request` class was actually defined when you `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`. This declaration tells PHP and Symfony to look for that class, probably using `spl_register_autoloader`, and include it in the current namespace, so that you can use the short name `Response` instead of the FQN.

4: PHP actually does a lookup for every class/function you call, searching first in the declared namespace, and then moving up to the global namespace. You should really read the documentation, it helped me out a lot while learning about these relatively new features (at least for PHP)

On #3, I have no idea, but I suppose that you can chose not to extend any other base class, should you choose to do so. Of course, this will not let your code inherit the methods set up by the parent classes, and you would have to implement those yourself. For example, not extending the base `Model` class would make you set up your connection to the database and such.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For Q3, Symfony 2 does provide a base controller class with some useful functions but you don't have to extend from it.  Any class will work.  Strongly suggest you just work you way through the manual step by step.  All your questions are not only answered but explained in detail.